# cygnus saving on mysql? I try this

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

How to configure Cygnus to save data on SQL database?
After installing Orion and Cosmos, I try to configure cygnus and save data on mysql database. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

With Cygnus you can save all the entities you want to by making a subscription to OrionCB. Yo can save it in differents formats including MySQL.

Anyway, you should visit [this Cygnus guide](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/) and read it before asking about. The guide is pretty clear about how cygnus work.